# Blog with heavy load of pictures-Speed up page

Tags: php, javascript, pagespeed

i'm building a travel blog (Php) where I might be loading dozens of pictures (size 500x375 weight 150-200kb) so that the page weights more than 4-5Mb.
Which is the way to go apart from caching/gzip to decrease waiting time and make a better user experience?

I'm on a shared server as my budget is very low

thanks

Comment: 500x375 == 200kb ??? Isn't that a bit high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

- split up the images across multiple pages
- use a 'lazy load' script that will only request images as they come into the viewport
- use AJAX to request images as needed via a user action
- leverage external hosting of the images (flickr, etc) to split the server requests amongst different servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're displaying dozens of images on one page, I would consider just showing small images / thumbnails that get enlarged when the visitor clicks on them.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points that solve this issue

1) Show few images and below that show more link or icon

2) After clicking on that give ajax call and show other images

3) Also you use 'jQuery lazy loading plugin'(it's very easy to integrate..[click here](http://sandeepshirsat.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/35/) to see integration step)